# How to call javascript controller method when a condition is met in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I want to call a javascript controller method from the lightning component when a condition is met. This is the code I used:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!product.stripePlanId == v.chosenProduct}">
     <aura:method name="getChosenProductName" action="{!c.getChosenProductName}" description="Sample method with parameters">
     </aura:method>
</aura:if>
```

`<aura:method>` i copied from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm). But, when I try to save this code, I get the following error in the `<aura:method>` line:

```
 c:ProductsComponent:91,157: Invalid attribute "name": Source
```

I couldn't figure out why. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

`aura:if` can have other html markup as body and not anything else. `aura:method` is like api layer for component so that parent component can communicate with this component. So, when you use `aura:method` as body of `aura:if`, it basically is thinking that it is html which ofcourse is invalid - there is no html tag **aura:method**

#### Solution:

You should have that condition in javascript method instead and have `aura:method` as the top most tag (direct child of `aura:component`)

CMP file:

```
 <aura:method name="getChosenProductName" action="{!c.getChosenProductName}" description="Sample method with parameters">
 </aura:method>
```

Controller JS:

```
getChosenProductName: function(component, event, helper) {
    if(component.get("v.product.stripePlanId") === component.get("v.chosenProduct")) {
        ...
    }
},
```

---

`aura:method` creates a api layer on component for parent components to interact. So, it is not really rendered in HTML of component but is rendered in Javascript. (Aura is a really weird implementation and LWC is more in line with standards). So, `aura:method` should always be the top most tag in cmp file.

Comment: even after removing the `<aura:if>`, i am still getting the error. I am calling this inside a `<aura:iteration>`. will that might be the problem?

Comment: yes, added in answer

Comment: K. thanks. So, is there any other way to call javascript method inside `aura:iteration`?

Comment: I want to change the value of `aura:attribute` when a condition is met inside an `aura:iteration`. Either I can call js method inside iteration to call `component.set()` inside that method,  or is there anyway to change the attribute value inside iteration itself without calling js method?

Comment: You need to use data- attributes in that case. You can close this question and create another question with full description with aura iteration

Comment: thanks very much. I have posted a new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/306876/82119