# How to change the value of aura:attribute inside a aura:iteration when a condition is met?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute, aura-method

I want to change the value of `aura:attribute` when a particular condition is met inside an `aura:iteration`. This is the code:

```
<aura:component>

     <aura:attribute name="products" type="List" />
     <aura:attribute name="chosenProductName" type="String" />

     <div class="row"> 
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.products}" var="product">
                <div class="column" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div style="background-color:#5E7BFC; padding:30px;">
                            <div class="headerStyle" style="background-color:#6B84F7;">
                                <span style="font-size:15px; color: white">{!product.productName}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <aura:method name="getChosenProductName" action="{!c.getChosenProductName}" description="Sample method with parameters"> 
                            </aura:method>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>

</aura:component>
```

I want to change the value of `chosenProductName` inside iteration. And this the code  I have tried so far. Call js controller method `getChosenProductName` using `aura:method` and update the value of `chosenProductName` inside that method when the  conditions are met. But, when I run this code, I get the following error in the `aura:method` line:

```
c:ProductsComponent:91,157: Invalid attribute "name": Source
```

So, what I have to do to solve this? **Either I need a way to call js method inside iteration to call component.set() inside that method, or is there anyway to change the attribute value inside iteration itself without calling js method?**

Comment: aura:method is used to provide a method to parent/related components, not for calling arbitrary code during rendering. You can't set an attribute while rendering, as there's no syntax for this, and doing so would cause an infinite rendering loop anyways. It's not clear what you're trying to do, exactly, but this direction isn't the way you want to go.

Comment: I just want to change the value of `aura:attribute` when a condition is met inside iteration.

Comment: How is the condition met?

Comment: actually, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/306864/82119 this is my previous question. I wanted to do a `aura:if` inside the iteration. But, it raised error and changed my plan to check condition inside js method, as mentioned in that question's answer.

Comment: You're stuck in an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You haven't explained what you're actually trying to do, but instead trying to get an invalid solution to work. What is your primary objective specifically?

Comment: I think, trying to change the attribute value inside lightning component was a mistake. I have changed my code as changing the attribute value when I get data in the helper js method itself. Its working fine. Anyway, thank u very much for the help.